# How to pick a inventory group name and break it via ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a inventory file which as follows :

```
[database21]
syd01-opscpoo-shared.ce4l1e4wl3z.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com
[database33]
syd01-desaasv-shared.re4l5of4bl3z.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

Now I need to actually read this inventory file and pick the following parts

```
syd01-opscpoo-shared

syd01-desaasv-shared
```

and save it in register variable , i am not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Open read the file and iterate line by line, use a string search with "contains", in this example i use 'amazonaws.com' assuming its similar for the lines that need to be split. After splitting the line into an array using dot as a delimiter, the first element should by the string you need.

```
def inputFile = new File('filename.txt')
if (inputFile.exists()) {
    inputFile.eachLine { line ->
        if(line.contains('amazonaws.com')) { //or use regex
            def result = line.split('.')[0]
            //do something with result
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to do it with Ansible ? This is a inventory file, i am looking for a `play`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first part of your hostname like this:

```
{{ item.split('.', 1) | first }}
```

Adjust it in your task. Hope that might help you.

Here is an example that how you can achieve your goal:

**hosts**:

```
[local]
localhost

[database21]
syd01-opscpoo-shared.ce4l1e4wl3z.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com

[database33]
syd01-desaasv-shared.re4l5of4bl3z.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com
```

**playbook.yml**:

```
---
- hosts: local
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.split('.', 1) | first }}"
      with_items: 
        - "{{ groups['database21'] }}"
        - "{{ groups['database33'] }}"
```

**Playbook result**:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts test.yml 

PLAY [local] *******************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=syd01-opscpoo-shared.ce4l1e4wl3z.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com) => {
    "item": "syd01-opscpoo-shared.ce4l1e4wl3z.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
    "msg": "syd01-opscpoo-shared"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=syd01-desaasv-shared.re4l5of4bl3z.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com) => {
    "item": "syd01-desaasv-shared.re4l5of4bl3z.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
    "msg": "syd01-desaasv-shared"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: how can i keep them in a register so i can use it further in play , also i need don't wanna hardcode the 'database' name instead i am running via a rapper from top

Comment: @PythonFreak can you please tell that how you want to use it in detail with example.

Comment: If i register the variable in the end , can i use it later ?

Comment: You can use the [set_fact](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/set_fact_module.html) module to store the value in the facts, which will persist across runs.